# How can I hash password every time it's changed in typeorm?

Tags: node.js, database, mongoose, typeorm, bcrypt

I am trying to hash password every time it has been changed in typeorm

```
@Column()
  password: string;

@BeforeInsert()
  async hashPassword() {
    this.password = await hash(this.password, 12);
  }
```

How can I replicate isModified functionality from mongoose in typeorm to hash password every time it has been changed like this:

```
if (this.password.isModified()) return next();
this.password = await hash(this.password, 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your password is modified, you will need to set in the object to be passed to the repository's save method. Save method updates an entity if it's the same id and some property changed. So you just need to use `@BeforeUpdate` inside your `@Entity`.

```
@BeforeUpdate()
private hashPassword(): void {
   this.password = myHashMethod(this.password);
}
```